# One Integral — Two Results

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I compared Mathematica's default integral evaluation to what you get by computing the indefinite integral and then plugging in the limits.

(I did this because the latter approach was much faster for some integrals.)

I got two different results:

```
integral=-Log[-a+b+2 a x+2 a Sqrt[(-1+x) x]]+Log[-a+b-2 b x+2 b Sqrt[(-1+x) x]]

integralDefault=Assuming[a>0&&b>0,Integrate[integral,{x,0,1}]]//Timing
(*I Pi/2*)

integralInDef[x]=Assuming[a>0&&b>0,Integrate[integral,x]]//Timing;
integralDef=Assuming[a>0&&b>0,Limit[integralInDef[x][[2]],x->1]-Limit[integralInDef[x][[2]],x->0]]//Timing
(*-I (a^2-8 a b+b^2) Pi/(4 a b)*)
```

The first result agrees with the numeric value.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: It does not look like a bug, known or unknown. It looks like an integral that might be crossing branch cuts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's useful to manipulate the integrand before integration; notice you have a negative number under square root :

```
simplifiedIntegrand = Simplify[ComplexExpand[integral, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, 0 < x < 1}]
(* I (-ArcTan[-a + b + 2 a x, 2 a Sqrt[(1 - x) x]] + 
       ArcTan[-a + b - 2 b x, 2 b Sqrt[(1 - x) x]]) *)

defIntegral =  Integrate[simplifiedIntegrand, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]
(* ConditionalExpression[I Pi/2, a <= b] *)

indefIntegral = Integrate[simplifiedIntegrand, x, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}] ;

defIntegral2 =  Assuming[a > 0 && b > 0, Limit[indefIntegral, x -> 1, Direction -> +1] - Limit[indefIntegral, x -> 0, Direction -> -1]]
(* (I Pi)/2 *)
```

As pointed out by @Simon :

```
Integrate[simplifiedIntegrand, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {a > b > 0}]
(* (I Pi)/2 *)
```

which would establish the identity `integral = I Pi /2` for any positive `a, b`.

However

```
general = Integrate[simplifiedIntegrand, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {a \[Element] Reals, b \[Element] Reals}]
(* ConditionalExpression[-(1/2) I (\[Pi] - 2 ArcTan[-a - b, 0] + 2 Arg[a + b]), 
    (b < 0 && (b <= a < 0 || 0 < a <= -b)) || (b > 0 && (-b <= a < 0 || 0 < a <= b))] *)
```

and

```
Simplify[general, Assumptions -> {0 < a < b}]
(* (I Pi)/2 *)
```

but

```
Simplify[general, Assumptions -> {a > b > 0}]
(* Undefined *)
```

Comment: If you do the integral `Integrate[simplifiedIntegrand, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {a > b > 0}]` you also get the answer `I Pi / 2`, so the result is stronger than the `ConditionalExpression` would have you think.

Comment: @Simon Good point, please see edit.